# Iteratively create columns based on grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got some data (below) where I want to iteratively add columns based on sums of current columns by some grouping variable, and I want to name the columns a pasted value of the current name + "_tot". I'm thinking a combination of dplyr and lapply is the way to go about it but I can't get the structure correct.

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(
    biz = sample(c("telco","shipping","tech"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    region = sample(c("mideast","americas"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    june = sample(1:50, 50, replace=TRUE),
    july = sample(100:150, 50, replace=TRUE)
    )
```

So, what I want to do is 1) group this data by "region", then add a new column for each of the following months that is the sum of that month's value (in the real dataframe, there are many periods that follow).

Basically, I want to apply this function

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(region) %>% mutate(june_tot = sum(june))
```

across every month, without having to specify "june" or "july". My initial take:

```
testfun <- function(df, col) {
    name <- paste(col, "_tot", sep="")
    data2 <- df %>% group_by(region) %>% summarise(name=sum(col))
    return(data2)
}
```

but lapplying this doesn't work, because I have to specify the columns to call into the initial function. Just removing the "col" argument from the initial function doesn't work either, of course.

Any ideas how to lapply this sort of argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are possible solutions to your problems using `dplyr` (first, since that is what you tried), and followed by `data.table` as well as `base R` solutions:

#### dplyr:

```
cols <- lapply(names(data)[-(1:2)], as.name)
names(cols) <- paste0(names(data)[-(1:2)], "_tot")
data %>% group_by(region) %>% mutate_each_q(funs(sum), cols)
```

Assumes every column but the first two are monthly data.  An explanation by line:

1. we use `as.name` and `lapply` to generate a list of the columns names we want to `mutate` as symbols
2. we give the new names we want (i.e. month_tot) to the list of symbols from 1.
3. we use the `mutate_each_q` (known as `mutate_each_` in `dplyr 0.3.0.2`) to apply `sum` to the list of expressions we created in 1. and 2.

This is the (sample) result:

```
Source: local data frame [50 x 6]
Groups: region

        biz   region june july june_tot july_tot
1  shipping  mideast   17  124      780     3339
2     telco americas   11  101      465     2901
3     telco  mideast   27  131      780     3339
4      tech americas   24  135      465     2901
... rows omitted
```

#### data.table:

```
new.names <- paste0(tail(names(data), 2L), "_tot")  # Make new names
data.table(data)[,
  (new.names):=lapply(.SD, sum),    # `lapply` `sum` to the selected columns (those in .SD), and assign to `new.names` columns
  by=region, .SDcols=-1             # group by `region`, and exclude first column from `.SD` (note `region` is excluded as well by reason of being in `by`
][]                                 # extra `[]` just to force printing
```

Here, similar logic, except we use the special `.SD` object that represents every column in the `data.table` that we are not grouping by.

#### base:

```
do.call(
  cbind, 
  list(
    data, 
    setNames(
      lapply(data[-(1:2)], function(x) ave(x, data$region, FUN=sum)),
      paste0(names(data[-(1:2)]), "_tot")
) ) )
```

Here we use `ave` to compute the per region sums, use `lapply` to apply `ave` to each column, and use `do.call(cbind, ...)` to reconstruct the final data frame.

Comment: +1, nice answer and an interesting approach. I wish this would be implemented in a different way, so that it could be easily defined inside the `mutate_each` in future versions. (btw, in dplyr 0.3.0.2 `mutate_each_q` is replaced by `mutate_each_`)

Comment: @beginneR, agree, this is the best I could think of.  Re `_q`, I realize, but I am too lazy to upgrade R to be able to use latest version of `dplyr`, so I'm stuck with it 0.2...

Comment: A more flexible naming of the output from `summarise_each_` seems to be a topic for next version of `dplyr`, see [**here**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/442)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but approach #1 is exactly what I was looking for (though great to know about data.table and base options as well). Had no idea "mutate_each_q" existed...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> for(i in 3:4) print(tapply(data[[i]], data$region, sum))
americas  mideast 
     563      768 
americas  mideast 
    2538     3802
```

You can get all outputs in a list if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring the data works well for this.

```
require(tidyr)
# wide to long
d2 <- gather(data = data,key = month,value = monthval,-c(biz,region))

# get totals and rename month
month_tots <- aggregate(x = list(total = d2$monthval),by = list(region = d2$region,month = d2$month),sum)
month_tots$month <- paste0(month_tots$month,'_tot')

# long to wide
month_tots <- spread(data = month_tots,key = month,value = total)

# recombine
merge(data,month_tots,by = 'region',all.x = T)
```