# data.table .SD in LHS of :=

Tags: r, data.table

This is in reference to a **[different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804362/iteratively-create-columns-based-on-grouped-variables/26805158#26805158)** where my original answer didn't quite work because it attempted to use `.SD` in the LHS:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(data)[,
  paste0(names(.SD), "_tot"):=lapply(.SD, sum), by=region, .SDcols=-1
][1:2]

#         biz  region june july _tot
# 1:    telco mideast    2  122  768
# 2: shipping mideast   29  111  768
```

but I really was hoping for what this does

```
new.names <- paste0(names(data[, -(1:2)]), "_tot")
data.table(data)[,
  (new.names):=lapply(.SD, sum), by=region, .SDcols=-1
][1:2]

#         biz  region june july june_tot july_tot
# 1:    telco mideast    2  122      768     3802
# 2: shipping mideast   29  111      768     3802
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is there another way to do this (refer to .SD in LHS of `:=`).

---

**EDIT**: thinking about this a bit more, clearly `.SD` cannot be available to the LHS, as the LHS should only have one value no matter how many groups, whereas `.SD` changes value for each group.  It also looks like there isn't a `.SDcols` variable or some such to use in LHS, but I'd be curious to see if others have better solutions that avoid a reference to the original `data` as I have here in constructing `new.names`.

Comment: Currently, the way you've done is the idiomatic way. But open to suggestions and/or pull requests ;-)

Comment: @Arun, slightly updated **[FR#795](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/795)**.  I'm not sure I'm in the position yet where I would dare mess with `data.table` source code, but maybe soon?

Comment: sure, thanks again. Will follow up once I've some time to look into this (may not be anytime soon though). On contributing, anytime you feel ready ;-).