# Dynamically build call for lookup multiple columns

Tags: r, dynamic, data.table, lookup

How can I dynamically lookup multiple fields and *add by reference* using character vector variable as argument. In below case I want to lookup two columns and get rid of `i.` prefix in them. Of course they can override already existing columns with the same name.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
ID <- data.table(id = 1:3, meta = rep(1,3), key = "id")
JN <- data.table(idd = sample(ID$id, 3, FALSE), value = sample(letters, 3, FALSE), meta = rep(1,3), key = "idd")
select <- c("value","meta") # my fields to lookup
j.lkp <- call(":=", select, lapply(paste0("i.",select), as.symbol))
j.lkp
# `:=`(c("value", "meta"), list(i.value, i.meta))
ID[JN, eval(j.lkp)]
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "i.value"
ID[JN, `:=`(c("value", "meta"), list(i.value, i.meta))]
#    id meta value
# 1:  1    1     x
# 2:  2    1     v
# 3:  3    1     f
```

I'm aware of [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677283/evaluating-both-column-name-and-the-target-value-within-j-expression-within-d) but this one asks for vectorized argument during join and directly building call for `j`.
edit: I'm aware I can do it using `.SDcols` but then I cannot perform this *by reference*

Comment: If you're replacing the entire column (as opposed to some matched subset of rows), I don't think modifying by reference does a lot for you. A `data.frame` is also a list of pointers to vectors; and I think they are modified in roughly the same way, like if you did `ID$value <- JN[match(idd,ID$id),value]`. The matching may be faster with `data.table` because you've set the keys, though.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, maybe you could illustrate what you mean about doing this with `.SDcols`... I don't think I follow.

Comment: Some kind of **first join, then subset**: `JN[ID][, setnames(.SD,"i....","..."),.SDcols=c(...)]`. Good point on matching whole column but I don't to sacrifice join speed (will do it also on composite key).

Comment: I guess it would be nice if we had additional shortcuts for columns and column names on both the left and right hand side of `j`, like `ID[JN,(.SDcols):=i.SD,.SDcols=select]`

Comment: On that last point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807217/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In recent development version it has been made much easier

```r
ID[JN, (select) := .list_of_fields,
   env=list(.list_of_fields=as.list(paste0('i.', select)))]
```

**OLD solution before 1.14.1**

Instead of `mget` or `eval-parse` there is still possibility to build the lookup call. While the `mget` is the most user friendly, this one is both flexible and actually corresponds to building the `j` expression.
Solution wrapped into `batch.lookup` helper function taking character vector of column names to lookup.

```r
    library(data.table)
    set.seed(1)
    ID <- data.table(id = 1:3, meta = rep(1,3), key = "id")
    JN <- data.table(idd = sample(ID$id, 3, FALSE), value = sample(letters, 3, FALSE), meta = rep(1,3), key = "idd")
    select <- c("value","meta") # my fields to lookup
    batch.lookup = function(x) {
        as.call(list(
            as.name(":="),
            x,
            as.call(c(
                list(as.name("list")),
                sapply(x, function(x) as.name(paste0("i.",x)), simplify=FALSE)
            ))
        ))
    }
    batch.lookup(select)
    #`:=`(c("value", "meta"), list(value = i.value, meta = i.meta))
    ID[JN, eval(batch.lookup(select))][]
    #   id meta value
    #1:  1    1     x
    #2:  2    1     v
    #3:  3    1     f
```

To be fair this answer actually address call construction issue described by me as OP.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be the most straightforward way to me:

```
ID[JN, (select) := mget(paste0('i.', select))]
```

Comment: `mget` seems to search in the wrong place. I get `Error: value for ‘i.value’ not found` on 1.9.4. Probably need to set the right environment.

Comment: Try with 1.9.5 - that's what I'm using

Comment: Okay, I can see that that issue has been fixed: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/994 Too much hassle to update the package at the moment (having to update rtools and such).

Comment: @Frank I believe you should be able to build package on separate machine and just install from compiled package (?)

Comment: `DT1[DT2, a:= get("i.b")]` uses much much more memory than  `DT1[DT2, a:= i.b]` in my machine, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the crude way:

```
myj <- parse(text=paste0("`:=`(",paste0(select,"=i.",select,collapse=","),")"))
ID[JN,eval(myj)]
#    id meta value
# 1:  1    1     x
# 2:  2    1     v
# 3:  3    1     f
```

Comment: @jangorecki There may be. I'm not well versed in `symbols`, `calls`, etc. and don't know what advantage that has over parsing characters (which is the format `select` starts in).

Comment: Memory usage does not explode using this method. Unlike `get()` method: `DT1[DT2, a:= get("i.b")]`

Comment: @user3226167 Yeah, `get` and `mget` may have some baggage in terms of loading stuff that might not be needed. Try `ID[JN, ls()]; ID[JN, {get("i.value"); ls()}]`. I don't really know the details, though. Jan's answer is a better way of building a call to eval than this one, fwiw.