# R Data Merge without Copying

Tags: r, data.table

In data.table, it is possible to work directly on the current data table (say DT) without creating a copy of it. For example, this can be done when creating a new column.

```
DT[,new_col:=1]
```

I would like to know how this can be done for merging, in particular left join. For example, the data table way of left join is

```
DT_right[DT_left,on="id"]
```

However, this does not modify the original DT_left table, requiring me to reassign. i.e.

```
DT_left = DT_right[DT_left,on="id"]
```

Is there a way for me to do this without reassigning? i.e. working on DT_left directly.

Comment: You want to add all column from `DT_right` to `DT_left`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468455/dynamically-build-call-for-lookup-multiple-columns/30469832#30469832).

Comment: Thanks for the response David. But I don't really see the connection. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I assumed this does exactly what you are looking for, so I don't know what to explain. Either-way, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how to post questions in a reproducible manner and please show your desired output.

Comment: I don't see where I get the i.value from

Comment: It sounds like the `dplyr` package might do what you want, but it's hard to say without seeing a reproducible example or knowing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @user3757897 How does *modifying in place* sounds like something that the dplyr package might do exactly?

Comment: @Jim If you don't know where to get `i.value` from, you should read some data.table tutorials. You can start [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, sorry, of course you're right. I was thinking of the pipe, but that would still require assignment. Apologies.

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have `DT_right` as

```
     id right_value
  1:  1           2
  2:  2           4
  3:  3           6
  4:  4           8
```

and `DT_left as`

```
    id left_value
 1:  1          3
 2:  2          6
 3:  3          9
 4:  4         12
```

if you want to perform left-join of `DT_left` on `DT_right` then `i.value` will be `i.left_value` i.e. the column name of the column you want to join from `DT_left` to `DT_right`.

```
DT_right[DT_left, joined_from_left := i.left_value, on = "id"]
DT_right[]
   id right_value joined_from_left
1:  1           2                3
2:  2           4                6
3:  3           6                9
4:  4           8               12
```